# How can i capture pictures with mechanicalsoup?

Tags: python, css-selectors, mechanicalsoup

```
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open(site+ssite)
print(browser.get_url())
r = browser.download_link('https://uygulama.gtb.gov.tr/FirmaSorgulama/Captcha/CaptchaImage')
with open('x.png', 'wb') as f:
f.write(r.content)
```

I am connecting to site with mechanical soup and in that page captcha appears. How can i capture same captcha and send forms ?( i am downloading capctha with requests but it changes since it is a new get)

Answer (score 1):

MechanicalSoup was designed to automate things on websites that were not specifically designed for automation (otherwise they'd provide a nice API), but not websites that were specifically designed to avoid automation, which is the case if you're trying to submit a form containing a CAPTCHA.

So, first, what you're trying to do goes against the will (and probably the terms and conditions) of the website and of MechanicalSoup's developers. There's no provision to help with CAPTCHAs in MechanicalSoup.